# Props not rendered when navigating to component directly - React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a problem with a react child component, using redux and react-router.

I'm getting a value from the URL through this.props.match.params to make an API call on componentDidMount. I'm using this.props.match.params as I want to use data from the API in my content if someone navigates to this particular URL directly.

When I navigate to the the component by clicking a  the component renders fine. The API is called via an action and the reducer dispatches the data to the relevant prop.

When I navigate to the component directly by hitting the URL, the API is called (I can see it called in the Network section of devtools), but the data isn't dispatched to the relevant prop and I don't see the content I expect.
I was hoping that by using this.props.match.params to pass a value to the API call I could hit the component directly and get the data from the API response rendered how I want.

Below is my component code. I suspect something is wrong with my if statement... however it works when I navigate to the component by clicking a Link within my React App.

What Am I missing?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { fetchData } from '../../actions';


    class Component extends React.Component {

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.fetchData(this.props.match.params.id);
        }

        renderContent() {
            if(!this.props.content) {
                return ( 
                    <article>
                        <p>Content loading</p>
                    </article>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <article>
                        <h2>{this.props.content.title}</h2>
                        <p>{this.props.content.body}</p>
                    </article>

                )
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <div className='centered'>
                        {this.renderContent()}
                    </div>
                </>
                )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return { post: state.content };
    }
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchData: fetchData })(Component);
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.props.match.params.id)` in `ComponentDidMount` and also `console.log(action)` in relevant reducer? Does it look right?

Comment: Yup, the look right when I click from Link, however when I navigate to the page directly I don't see either log in my console.

Comment: The error I'm getting is TypeError: cannot read property of undefined, which suggests to me the problem is in the render function, before the component mounts.
This also suggests to me the if statement is being ignored...even though this.props.content doesn't exist that statement is being ignored on render and the else statement is being returned. I'm genuinely confused by this.

Comment: Do you see "Content loading" when you navigate directly?

Comment: you havent bind  `this` to `renderContent`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `renderContent` to this:

```
        renderContent = () => {
            if(!this.props.content) {
                return ( 
                    <article>
                        <p>Content loading</p>
                    </article>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <article>
                        <h2>{this.props.content.title}</h2>
                        <p>{this.props.content.body}</p>
                    </article>

                )
            }
        }
```

It looks like you forgot to bind `this` to `renderContent`

Comment: console.log(action) in the reducer is a useful trick to know :) thanks for that!

I tried this but I'm still getting the same problem. I add...
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.renderContent = this.renderContent.bind(this);
    }

but still no joy

Comment: You never get `<p>Content loading</p>` rendered in ui?

Comment: The UI doesn't render at all when I hit the page directly. renderContent() is definitely running, but it's trying to run the else statement, hence the error TypeError: cannot read property title of undefined, which refers to <h2>{this.props.content.title}</h2>

In the console I can see that this.props.content returns undefined, and the network request to the API isn't being made.

When I hit the page through react router (clicking the Link element) the page renders as expected.

Comment: when hitting the page directly I can see the action logged to the console as
{type: "@@redux/INIT7.9.k.6.w.x"}
type: "@@redux/INIT7.9.k.6.w.x"
__proto__: Object

to me it looks like renderContent is running the conditional incorrectly.. attempting to run the else statement when the if condition is met and this.props.content doesn't exist... which prevents the component from mounting (hence the API isn't called)

Comment: Can you replace `{this.renderContent()}` with "hello World" - just to be sure that this component renders. Maybe there is some other conditional up in the component tree which exclude this component from rendering. Another thing that concerns me is `class Component extends React.Component {`. Let rename it  to something else (e.g MyComponent). Do not forget to update export.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, huge thanks for your help!

It turned out the API request was returning an array, and my action was dispatching this array to props.content.
This particular API call will always return an array with just one value (according to the documentation it's designed to return a single entry... but for some reason returns it in an array!). I was expecting an object so I was treating it as such.
I converted the array into an object in my reducer and now it's behaving as it should.

So overall turned out to be a problem with my data structure.